# Giving permission to a particular user to start/stop a particular service

Tags: php, linux, service, sudo

I want to give permission to a normal user to start/stop a particular service only. Then how can i tweak the sudoers file to achieve this?

Comment: Where's the connection to PHP?

Comment: I too had the same issue. I am trying to start a service using php shell_exec .

Comment: @Alfe using php shell_exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this entry in the sudoers file

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/Servicename *
```

If you are using php_exec,

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/servicename *
```

Apache is the user who runs the webserver. It is www-data in some OS.

Also dont forgot to comment out

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

in sudoers file.